# HP printer won't print

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, hp

I just attached a HP Deskjet 3510 printer to my Ubuntu 12.04 computer via USB, which works with other devices.  The printer is not recognized by HPLIP, as the device manager says "No Installed HP Devices Found."  When I try to print a test page from the print icon properties, nothing prints although the printer state says "Idle - Rendering completed."  However, a self-test page is printed OK directly from the printer itself.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can print but you can't?
You mean you can press a button to do a printer self test on the printer, and that works(that involves no interaction with no OS) but a test page sent from Ubuntu doesn't work? Which seems logical when it is not installed.
Sorry, but the text you provided was a little confusing to read.

Answer (score 2):

If you open **System Settings** and click on **Printers** does the printer show up? Look in the "/dev" directory, is there a "usb" folder?

```
~$ ls /dev/usb
lp0
~$
```

If you don't have an **lp** in your **usb** directory I would suggest trying some other usb ports on your machine or trying other devices in that port. USB ports are notorious for becoming faulty, usually due to constant plugging action and the fact they have power running through them.

I didn't have to do a damn thing for my HPDJ3512. It didn't even ask me to install anything, it just showed up.

Answer (score 2):

My printer (HP LaserJet 1020) was working when I first plugged it in to my Ubuntu laptop and then for some reason after some time it no longer did jobs successfully. My computer apparently was sending the data to the printer successfully but the printer would just sit there doing nothing

**Using `sudo hp-setup` in the terminal** put me through an installation wizard that, when finished, got my printer working. Apparently Ubuntu comes with the `hp-setup` functionality.

Hope this helps another--

Answer (score 0):

Today I solved the riddle of why the new HP-Deskjet 2510 All-in-one, (Ubuntu-1204) would not print despite having followed documentation, advice given here (upgraded hplip, etc). I acquired an old Epson Stylus CX3810, missing ink cartridge and all, hooked it up turned it on, ran hp-setup, there it was found and ready to go. huh? What was different? I used an old USB printer cable, hmm.. switched it to the HP-Deskjet, there it was found and ready to go. Lesson? Just because a USB printer cable is new and for the printer does not mean it works. Thanks to all that helped.